# Is parasocial love a romantic relationship?

Tags: social-psychology

Is parasocial love is a form of romantic relationship?
I have read about some articles about parasocial love and have come across the term "parasocial romantic relationships" is this the same as "parasocial love"?

Comment: Could you include a link and citation to one or more of the articles in which you found this in an edit to your question?

Answer (score 1):

**Parasocial interaction**

Parasocial interaction can definitely lead to a parasocial relationship

[SMU](https://ink.library.smu.edu.sg/lkcsb_research_all/7/)

> parasocial relationships mediated the relationships between social media interactions and source trustworthiness, (2) social media interactions influenced parasocial relationships via self-disclosure;and (3) source trustworthiness had a positive effect on brand credibility, which, in turn, led to purchase intention. Implications for research and practice are discussed.

**Dr Sandra L. Calvert**

[Dr Sandra L. Calvert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandra_L._Calvert) talks about the effects of Parasocial interaction and uses News anchors as a good example of how we can wrongfully begin to trust a media personality and grow an attachment to this person and wrongfully believe this person is speaking directly to us.

[Wired](https://www.wired.com/2016/02/room-fandom-psychology/)

> Parasocial interactions were first investigated in regards to their effects on adults watching TV newscasters. News anchors have almost always spoken directly to the camera, fostering the notion that they’re speaking directly, almost exclusively, to viewers watching in their living rooms. The parasocial relationship that forms allows the newscaster to seem as though they're intimately connected with the viewer, similar to Jack’s connection to Dora or Mildred’s connection to the characters in The Family.

> These parasocial interactions impact human beings in both a cognitive and emotional way, Calvert says. It's in the overlap of the two that “feeling something” can become easily confused for “knowing something.” Parasocial relationships can help a person suspend disbelief, and engage more viscerally with worlds they see on television, in a film, or while playing a videogame.

**Parasocial Romantic Relationship**

A parasocial relationship can easily turn in to a parasocial romantic relationship, and there is a book on the subject called Parasocial Romantic Relationships and it explains how PRS can turn in to one-sided love.

[PRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1793609586)

> Parasocial Romantic Relationships: Falling in Love with Media Figures explores how, why, and to what effect individuals develop romantic feelings toward people they "know" from the media. These imaginary, one-sided relationships, dubbed parasocial romantic relationships, are both profound and pervasive, Riva Tukachinsky Forster argues. These relationships can take many forms, including adolescents who develop celebrity crushes on popular music artist, anime enthusiasts who "marry" their favorite characters, and fanfiction authors who insert themselves into narratives as romantic interests of the protagonist.

**Parasocial break up**

There is also such a thing as Parasocial break up, which happens when a media figure dies or stops going on air, and this can be quite distressing for an individual, particularly if it is an individual that has fell victim to PRS.

[Digital Scholarship](https://digitalscholarship.unlv.edu/thesesdissertations/2392/)

> The study of one-sided mediated interactions, commonly known as parasocial interactions, have generated significant investigations which have examined both mediated relationships through television, the Internet, other media, and the discontinuation of these relationships (also known as parasocial breakups). These studies have specifically identified certain trends in which respondents have tended to form strong emotional connections with subject(s) within narrative fictional depictions. This study examines the relationship between parasocial breakup and the dissolution of a viewer following the end of primetime series, How I Met Your Mother.

**Is parasocial love a romantic relationship?**

For someone that has became a victim of parasocial interaction and went all the way to developing feelings of love, to the point where they're liable to suffer from parasocial break up, then It could definitely be described as a one-sided romantic relationship.